# Problemas al generar una tabla con php desde un array bidimensional

Tags: php, html, html5, array, php5

Hola éste es mi código y a pesar de que le pongo el rowspan a 3 no me genera la tabla correctamente, trato de generar una tabla a partir de un array bidimensional con PHP pero al dar formato a la tabla no sale como debería, no encuentro el error, por favor una ayuda.

```
<table border="1">  
    <?php
    //Primero creamos dos arrays $matriz_pablo y $matriz_roberto para luego insertarlas en un array general $matriz_general la que sera bidimensional
    $matriz_pablo = array('nombre' => 'pablo', 'profesion' => 'ministro', 'edad' => '50');
    $matriz_roberto = array('nombre' => 'roberto', 'profesion' => 'agricultor', 'edad' => '45');
    $matriz_general = array('PABLO' => $matriz_pablo,'ROBERTO' => $matriz_roberto);
    //A continuación imprimimos los valores de la matriz bidimensional.
    //El Primer FOREACH muestra las claves de primer nivel PABLO y ROBERTO
    foreach ($matriz_general as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>"."<td rowspan='3'>".$key."</td>";//Se muetra la Clave
            //El Segundo FOREACH mostrará las claves y valores de segundo nivel internos de la columna valor de primer nivel.
            foreach ($value as $clave => $valor) {
                echo "<tr>"."<td>".$clave."</td>"."<td>".$valor."</td>"."</tr>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Si le pones `rowspan=4` te funcionará como (creo) que esperas: **`<td rowspan='4'>`**

Comment: Hola mi estimado, gracias por la ayuda y si funciona. Rowspan, indica el número de filas que ocupará la celda, entonces no logro identificar cual es la cuarta fila q estoy ocupando involuntariamente.

Comment: La cuarta fila es precisamente aquella donde está el `rowspan`. Si observas mi respuesta verás que hay 4 filas, una fila es la que tiene el nombre en mayúscula y luego las tres filas para `nombre, profesion, edad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si esperas una tabla como esta en resultado:

```html
    <table border="1">

  <! fila 1->
        <tr>
            <td rowspan='4'>PABLO</td>
        </tr>

  <! fila 2->
        <tr>
            <td>nombre</td>

            <td>pablo</td>
        </tr>

  <! fila 3->
        <tr>
            <td>profesion</td>

            <td>ministro</td>
        </tr>

  <! fila 4->
        <tr>
            <td>edad</td>

            <td>50</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td rowspan='4'>ROBERTO</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>nombre</td>

            <td>roberto</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>profesion</td>

            <td>agricultor</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>edad</td>

            <td>45</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Tienes que cambiar <s>`echo "<tr>"."<td rowspan='3'>".$key."</td>";`</s> por esto: `echo "<tr>"."<td rowspan='4'>".$key."</td>";`, porque son 4 filas las que quieres juntar, no 3.

O bien, plantear otra forma de crear la tabla.

Answer (score 1):

estaba analizando el código y creo que logré resolverlo con rowspan = "3" eliminando una de las etiquetas  y bajando un nivel el td

```
<table border="1">  
    <?php
    //Primero creamos dos arrays $matriz_pablo y $matriz_roberto para luego insertarlas en un array general $matriz_general la que sera bidimensional
    $matriz_pablo = array('nombre' => 'pablo', 'profesion' => 'ministro', 'edad' => '50');
    $matriz_roberto = array('nombre' => 'roberto', 'profesion' => 'agricultor', 'edad' => '45');
    $matriz_general = array('PABLO' => $matriz_pablo,'ROBERTO' => $matriz_roberto);
    //A continuación imprimimos los valores de la matriz bidimensional.
    //El Primer FOREACH muestra las claves de primer nivel PABLO y ROBERTO
    foreach ($matriz_general as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>"."<td rowspan='3'>".$key."</td>";//Se muetra la Clave
            //El Segundo FOREACH mostrará las claves y valores de segundo nivel internos de la columna valor de primer nivel.
            foreach ($value as $clave => $valor) {
                echo "<td>".$clave."</td>"."<td>".$valor."</td>"."</tr>";
            }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que ese código te crea una tabla válida, cerrando, sin abrir, el `</tr>` dentro del segundo `for`?